# Tax consequences (future or present) of giving up US citizenship

Tags: taxes, international, citizenship, foreign-income

I am a Norwegian citizen by birth, and have lived here all my life. Some years ago, I learned that I am - by virtue of a US parent - also a citizen of the latter country. The amusement of learning that fact quickly gave way to a horror story of realizing the tax obligations US citizens are under when "abroad" (imagine how writing that feels, when "abroad" really means your home since birth). The first year after I learned, I followed IRS advice online and filed a few years of back-returns (all entirely covered by FEIE as far as I can tell, resulting in 0 net US tax) and FBARs, and have since then filed them to the best of my ability. I have not heard anything back, which I take as a good sign.

I am now coming up on the time when I believe I fulfill the requirements for giving up my US citizenship (such as having filed tax returns for the previous years), and am considering doing so. (Legal note: This is **not** something I am considering for tax purposes; I simply feel I have no connection with the US, and that is no good basis for holding a citizenship I never asked for). I am, however, hearing rumours that there can be financial consequences of giving up such a citizenship. In particular, can anybody shed any light on the following:

- I am not a wealthy person. In net terms I am in debt. Am I understanding the regulations correctly that this should impose no "leaving tax" on me?
- What happens if I, at a later stage in life, and obviously then as a *foreigner* were to take a job in the US? I am hearing rumours that as an ex-citizen I would be financially in a much worse position than any "regular foreigner". Is there any truth to this?

Thank you.

Comment: You certainly won't be able to work in the US if you renounce your citizenship. You could come on a tourist visa.

Comment: @Rocky: That is an overstatement.  Plenty of non-citizens work in the US.  You will definitely need a visa, but people do obtain work visas that let them stay much longer than a tourist visa.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not a wealthy person. In net terms I am in debt. Am I
>   understanding the regulations correctly that this should impose no
>   "leaving tax" on me?

[Expatriation tax](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Expatriation-Tax) is imposed on people with personal wealth of $2M or tax liability of $147K - $157K a year for the last 5 years, or if you're out of compliance for the last 5 years (which from what you describe - you may be).

For 10 years after you renounce your citizenship, the US may still tax you as a citizen if you're present in the US for more than 30 days a year.

> What happens if I, at a later stage in life, and obviously then as a
>   foreigner were to take a job in the US? I am hearing rumours that as
>   an ex-citizen I would be financially in a much worse position than any
>   "regular foreigner". Is there any truth to this?

Once the 10 years pass, you're as foreigner as anyone else.

In any case, you'll need to get a proper visa and work authorization to work in the US. Being ex-citizen may complicate this step slightly, from the USCIS/consular/immigration officers' perspective, as they may assume you're trying to repatriate in some way and will put your intentions under extra scrunity.